# How do I have an image that when you mouseover shows a tooltip that contains a table?

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip, mouseover

I have been trying to do this for 1day and 6 hours (literally) and I am pulling my hair out. I have tried google wayy to much that I have ran out of searches and combination of words and have even been back to the links I visted before just to check if I missed anything.

What I need is: When someone moves their mouse over an image, it displays a tooltip. That being the easy part in which I have figured out. The hard part is putting a table in that tooltip so it organizes what I wish to show. An exact replica of what I need is at http://occultdarkr.enjin.com/
I also need it to follow the mouse and have the opacity like the one in the site.

I have tried many things when it came to adding tables in a tooltip however it never shows the table. It either shuts down the tooltip so nothing shows or it shows the actual code for the table. Real pain. I tried using javascript and jquery stuff that I have found on the net, nothing works with what I need though.

Please any helpful help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you tell which language do you use for your website please? it can help to give you an accurate answer (also perhaps could you post some of your actual code to get an idea of how you're doing this right now)

Comment: It's all mainly php but I inline javascript, jquery and css into it.

Comment: and your tooltip is contained in a div I imagine? Also are you using some third party code to make the tooltip?

Comment: Havent used a div, most recently I tried <img src="http://localhost/ec_sprite.jpg" onMouseover="ddrivetip('<table><tr><td><font color="#ff0000">test</font></td></tr><table>')";
onMouseout="hideddrivetip()">

Comment: Also yes I am using 3rd party code I believe, using code from helpful sites I find that offer web design assistance.

Comment: I believe the `ddrivetip` function is third party code? Your problem can be here, I think it converts everything into string (well escapes html characters), that's why you see the code of your table instead of the table itself

Answer (score 2):

There are two way to do that,
One of them that you can implement tooltip with jquery function such as like below,

```
$("p").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).append('<span id='sth'><table><tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></table></span>');
}).mousedown(function(){
    $("#sth").remove();
});
```

next one, you can use some jQuery tooltip plugin like,

1. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/
2. http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/
3. http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/
4. http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html
5. http://codylindley.com/Javascript/264/jtip-a-jquery-tool-tip
6. http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip.html
7. http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/
8. http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

I would first try to put your table in a hidden div, or create the div dynamically with your table data when you want to show it (absolute position ...), then you add a function on the onmousemove event where you change your div position (make it the mouse position) and that should do it

if you need more precision feel free to ask I'll edit my answer if needed

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code that you can modify according to your needs.

HTML

```
<img class="HelpIcon" src="help.png"  title="<table border='1'><tr><td>1</td><td>First Item</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Second Item</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Third Item</td></tr></table>"  />
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var txt = "";
    $('.HelpIcon').mouseenter(function () {
        txt = $(this).attr('title');

        $(this).attr('title', '');
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var $tooltip = $('<div></div>')
        .attr('id', 'HelpDiv')
        .css('margin-left', offset.left)
        .html(txt);

        $(this).after($tooltip);


    });

    $('.HelpIcon').mousemove(function (e) {
        $("#HelpDiv").css('left',e.pageX);
        $("#HelpDiv").css('top',e.pageY); 
    });

    $('.HelpIcon').mouseleave(function () {

        $('#HelpDiv').remove();
        $(this).attr('title', txt);



    });

});
```